# How to take a Use Case to Unit Test

Tags: c#, tdd

Here's my Use Case
[image]

To start writing unit tests in TDD, I need to come up with classes and methods to test, e.g. `ClassUnderTest.MethodUnderTest()`

The nouns are: `Candidate`, `Admin`, `User`, `Account`, `Credentials`, `Password`, `ResumeWidget` (the system), and last but not least, `SomeOtherAbstractionIDidNotThinkOf` (e.g. `SecurityService`).

The verbs are: `Login()`, `Logout()`, `Register()`, `CreateAccount()`, `RecoverPassword()`, `Unlock()`, `ResetPassword()`, `Lockout()`, and last but not least, `SomeOtherActionIDidNotThinkOf()`.

To make this question most simple, let's see if we can stick with `Login()`. Let me see if I can start a Unit Test for that method.

Would you have a Login method somewhere?

If so, what Class would you put it in? Why?

If not, what Class and Method would you use? And Why?

Comment: What you're asking is not unit testing, but a functional testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give you a small hint about how to start TDD. First, think about how to design your software based on your use case.(Ex: Account class can contain login, logout and etc., methods)

```
[TestFixture]
public class AccountTest
{
   public Account underTest;

   [SetUp]
   public void setUp()
   {
     underTest = new Account();
   }

   [Test]
   public void TestLoginWithValidCredentials()
   { 
      bool isValid = underTest.Login('userName', 'password');         
      Assert.True(isValid );
   }

   [Test]
   public void TestLoginWithInValidCredentials()
   {
       bool isValid = underTest.Login('', '');         
       Assert.False(isValid );
   }

   [Test]
   //Assert Expected Lockout exception here
   public void TestLockoutByPassingInValidCredentialsMoreThan5Times()
   {

       for (int i =0; i< 5; i++)
       {     
          bool isValid = underTest.Login('', '');    
          Assert.False(isValid );     
       }           
        // the system should throw an exception about lockout
        underTest.Login('', ''); 
   }      

   [Test]
   public void TestCreateAccount()
   {
      //Register event can directly call this method
      bool isCreated = underTest.Create(/*User Object*/);
      Assert.True(isCreated );
   }

   [Test]
   public void TestLogout()
   {
      bool success = underTest.Logout('userName');          
      Assert.True(success);          
   }

   [Test]
   public void TestReset()
   {
      // both Unlock and RecoverPassword event can share this method
      bool success = underTest.Reset('userName');          
       // mock the password reset system and return the expected value like 'BSy6485TY'
      Assert.AreEqual('BSy6485TY', password);
   }       
}
```

Updated: Added more test cases to help you to design your system.

Comment: [Use Case] -> [Miracle Goes Here] -> [Unit Test]. I have no doubt you are very agile mentally. You just looked at it and quickly / easily came up with something that looks very simple and quite correct. If I could do what you just did, I'm sure I would have created a Unit Test and not an S/O question. I'm quite impressed, but it's kinda like when Arnold says, "If you want big biceps, just do 50 curls with this 150Kg dumbbell" lol. Do you have any insight about the internal structure of [Miracle] (as you say, "think about")? That's my question. And thanks, very nice.

Comment: @toddmo, You are right about my agile way of solving problem. I usually start writing the test cases from simple and well known features like valid and invalid credentials and I strongly believe that a small correct steps is better than a very long failure step. I updated my answer and i hope it will definitely solve your doubts.

Comment: What all went into your decision to put the `Login()` method on an `Account` class instead of a `User` or `Security` or `SecurityService` or `Session` class?

Comment: Of course you should do those refactoring because It's very essential. Now, your test cases will help you, If you do any mistakes during code refactoring (This is one of the benefit of using TDD).